# Repository getting from model not working

Tags: laravel

I have the following repository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Employee;

class EmployeeRepository
{

    protected $employee;

...

    public function getAllManagersList(Employee $employee)
    {
        $managers = $employee->getAllManagers();
        $result = Array();
        foreach ($managers as $manager)
        {
            $result[$manager->id] = $manager->first_name . ' ' . $manager->last_name;
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Which is calling the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class Employee extends Model {

    protected $table = 'employees';

    public $timestamps = true;

...

    public function getAllManagers()
    {
        $managers = DB::table('employees')->select(['id','first_name','last_name'])->orderBy('last_name')->where('is_manager','=','1')->get();
        return $managers;
    }


}
```

And my controller is calling it with this:

```
public function create(EmployeeRepository $employeeRepository)
{
    $manager_list = $employeeRepository->getAllManagersList();
    //\Debugbar::info($manager_list);
    return view('employees/create')->with('manager_list',$manager_list);
}
```

but when I run this, I get the following:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\EmployeeRepository::getAllManagersList() must be an instance of App\Employee, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\people\app\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController.php on line 31
```

I am trying to get this in a neat way so that I can have my model only doing the db requests and my repository to tidy it up so that it appears nicely in my page. That's why I try to call it from the controller to the repository to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `$employeeRepository->getAllManagersList();`.

But the function is defined as : 
`public function getAllManagersList(Employee $employee)`.

Comment: sorry I don' understand what you mean... why isn't it working. I thought you could inject a class like this...

Comment: There's a missing parameter.